Estimation of the absolute value of the $n$th non-real zero of the Riemann zeta function
Recently, I have been studying the oringinal proof of the prime number theory by Hadamard. I didn't get it on the estimation of the absolute value of the $n$th non-real zero of the $\zeta$ function by the coefficient of the series form of the $\Theta$ function.
Let $\rho_n$ denote the $n$th non-real zero of the Riemann zeta function according to the absolute value and $\theta_n$ the $n$th zero of the $\Theta$ function, I want to figure out why:
$$|\theta_n|\sim C_1\frac{n}{\ln n}$$and thus$$|\rho_n|\sim C_2\frac{n}{\ln n}$$
and I have already known that
$$\Theta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}s^{2n}$$
$$c_1^n\frac{(\ln n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\leq |a_{2n}|\leq c_2^n\frac{(\ln 2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
where $\Theta(z)=-\frac{1}{2}(z^2+\frac{1}{4})\pi^{-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{zi}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{zi}{2})\zeta(\frac{1}{2}
+zi)$.
By the way, I would bound $|\frac{\zeta^{'}}{\zeta}(z)|$ when $\operatorname{Re}(z)<1$ for some large $z$ by using the formula above, if you are interested.
Could anyone help me? Thanks.
I would appreciate it if you could provide solutions or just some thoughts for my problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

thx for reminding, i'v added further information!

If $\rho_n=\beta_n+i\gamma_n$, then the number $N(T)$ of zeros such that $0<\gamma_n\le T$ is asymptotically
$$
N(T)\sim{T\over2\pi}\log T,
$$
so setting $T=\gamma_n$ gives
$$
n\sim{\gamma_n\over2\pi}\log\gamma_n
$$
Taking logarithms on both sides gives $\log n\sim\log\gamma_n$, so we have
$$
\gamma_n\sim{2\pi n\over\log n}.
$$

Thanks for your answer, but actually I need the result above to prove the estimation of $N(T)$, so you kind of use a stronger conclusion. Or could you give a proof without the result? If so I would also be very thankful.

The proof of the asymptotic for $N(T)$ does not required such estimate. See my blog and my answer here for details.

Thanks. It's much longer than I thought.
